# Adding freshly created formula into new module

Tags: excel, vba

I've just created a brand new macro. Took function down below from internet (all credits goes to trumpexcel.com), code down below

```
    Function CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Ref As Range, Separator As String) As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Result As String
For Each Cell In Ref
 Result = Result & Cell.Value & Separator
Next Cell
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Then I proceed to extract data from various columns and into the one (my table is 20 rows x 10 columns)

```
Sub conact_data()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(i, "M").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value & " " & _
        Cells(i, "B").Value & " / " & Cells(i, "D").Value & "; "
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks to that I've got combined data from column A, B and D, so its 20 rows. All I want to do now is to concatenate data from M2:M21 using CONCATENATEMULTIPLE function therefore I try various approach (I want this huge line in P2 cell) like :

```
Cells(2, 16).Value = CONCATENATEMULTIPLE (M2:M21, " ")
```

or

```
Range("P2") = "CONCATENATEMULTIPLE (M2:M21, " ")"
```

I don't really know how to apply that

Secondly, I'd like withdraw the `Cells(i, "B").Value` as percentage. Can I do that in one line like `Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat="0.00%".Value` (which is not working for me obviously) else I need to copy column B into another column with number format and then combine the new column, properly formatted instead of column B?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Percent format:** `Range("B" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

---

**CONCATENATEMULTIPLE**

In VBA, `CHR(32)` = `" "`
In Excel, `CHAR(32)` = `" "`

With that being said...

```
'Value
Range("P2").Value = CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Range("M2:M21"), CHR(32))

'Formula
Range("P2").Formula = "=CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(M2:M21, CHAR(32))"
```

---

*You should really qualify all of your ranges with a worksheet*

Say your workbook has 10 sheets. When you say `Range("P2")`, how do we (VBE) know what sheet you mean? Objects need to be properly qualified. Sometimes this is not a huge issue, but when you are working across multiple sheets, not qualifying ranges can lead to some unexpected results.

You can qualify with a worksheet a few ways.

> Directly: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P2").Copy`

Or use a variable like so

> ```
> Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
> ws.Range("P2").Copy
> ```

Now there is no room for ambiguity (potential errors) as to the **exact** location of `Range("P2")`

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your reply @urdearboy, P2 value works perfectly, however percentage format not, when I change Cells(i, "B").Value into Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "0.00%" or copy paste your solution with range, I get "FALSE" statements. 

Moreover, could you elaborate about qualifying all of my ranges with a worksheet?

Comment: You may need to check to make sure it is a number. Try `MsgBox IsNumeric(Range("B" & i))`. If this returns FALSE, then your cell is not a true number, rather a text string masquerading as a number

Comment: Susprisingly it gives TRUE @urdearboy

Oh I see what you've meant with ranges within worksheets, forunately I am making this as a help for a friend, he will extract the same sized table everyday and run the macro to get all of that in one line so he can post it further

Comment: Try `MsgBox Range("B" & i)`. Is this the correct value you want to format? There may be a issue with `i`. Otherwise, I don't know what is going on there. I can't replicate - the code I provided works fine for me. That may deserve it's own question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove your ConcatenateMultiple() code, and instead use Excel worksheet function CONCAT(), which takes a range and a delimiter as parameters.

Here is how you can handle the percentage issue and supply a default for non-numeric items.  I've also cleaned up the way you reference your data range.

```
Sub concat_data()
    Dim rngRow As Range, vResult As Variant
    Const DEFAULT = 0   'Can also be set to a text value, eg. "Missing"

    For Each rngRow In [A2].CurrentRegion.Rows
        If IsNumeric(rngRow.Cells(, 4)) Then vResult = rngRow.Cells(, 4) * 100 & "%" Else vResult = DEFAULT
        Range("M" & rngRow.Row) = rngRow.Cells(, 1) & rngRow.Cells(, 2) & "/" & vResult & ";"
    Next
    [M2].End(xlDown).Offset(1).Formula = "=CONCAT(M2:M" & [M2].End(xlDown).Row & ",TRUE,"" "")"
End Sub
```

I'm not a fan of hard-coding range references, like the [A2] or Range("M"), but will leave that for another time.

Comment: Thank you very much @Allen, code works but could you tell me whether line Const DEFAULT = 0 is needed? I'd never though of that line while doing this

Moreover, got one concern. This will be data from market index, and when its like 65,80 per share, its good for a macro because its concat as 65.80 as vba separate by using dot, not comma, however when its higher value, its extracted as for example 7 795,00 and then its still 7 795,00 for VBA. Is there any particular method to change it into, lets say 7.795.00 ?

Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: Not absolutely needed, as you can just put that value in place of the "vDefault" variable, however it is the "right" way to do it.  Regarding the dot/comma issue, you must be using a different localization than mine; I cannot reproduce this, so cannot address that issue.